# How to develope 2 Google App Engine projects on the same PC?

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, email-address

A year ago I used my own personal gmail account to develop my 1st Google App Engine program, I'm still developing and using it, I have 2 apps under this private account.

Now I have registered another App Engine app with another gmail account for an organization and their project, but when I tried to deploy this second project for the first time, I've noticed the following:

---

```
20% Scanning files on local disk.
25% Initiating update.
Password for ABC***@gmail.com: 
Error Details: .....
```

"ABC***@gmail.com" is my private gmail account which was/is used for the 1st project, I didn't want to include the 2nd project in the 10 apps of my 1st project, that's why I registered the 2nd project with the 2nd gmail address, so my question is : how to tell the 2nd project to use the 2nd gmail address for that project ? Where is the gmail address associated with the project in the config files ?

PS : I'm running Win 7, and using NetBeans 7.0 with App Engine 1.5

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: what OS are you running on? Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you may want to try AppCfg, a command line tool provided with GAE SDK. You can find it in $GAE_FOLDER$/bin. The command for uploading your project is
`appcfg -e YOUREMAIL -passin YOURPASS update YOURAPP_DIR`.

Comment: You can find appcfg.cmd/sh for windows/linux environment. Actually it's a shortcut for a Java application.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Since I'm using Netbeans, I wonder if there is anything I can do so when I press a customized button in it, it will run my script for each project ?

Comment: I believe [this plugin](http://kenai.com/projects/nbappengine/pages/Home) is what you're looking for. However you can always create your own .cmd/.sh to do the task rather than relying on 3rd party plugins.

Comment: Yes, exactly, and I've been using it, but it only seems to be able to deal with one of my gmail accounts, I don't know how to use it for the 2nd project with the 2nd gmail address for that project. Is it smart enough to associate different gmail address with different projects ? So far it can only associate both my projects with my 1st gmail address. And that's why I'm asking question here.

Comment: `--passin` accepts the password on standard in, not as a command line argument. It also has two hyphens preceding it, not one.

Comment: @Frank then I suppose the .cmd/.sh is the best way to help you.